# How to define simple programming language grammar that mix statements and expressions grammar just like Scala/Rust?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar

I'm learning grammar of Scala/Rust and try to define myself a toy language grammar. I found their grammar mixed Imperative language syntax and Functional language grammar, in other words, statements are also expressions, statements have return value.

In Scala grammar, for example:

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/13-syntax-summary.html

```
  Expr              ::=  (Bindings | [‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘=>’ Expr
                      |  Expr1
  Expr1             ::=  ‘if’ ‘(’ Expr ‘)’ {nl} Expr [[semi] ‘else’ Expr]
                      |  ‘while’ ‘(’ Expr ‘)’ {nl} Expr
                      |  ‘try’ Expr [‘catch’ Expr] [‘finally’ Expr]
                      |  ‘do’ Expr [semi] ‘while’ ‘(’ Expr ‘)’
                      |  ‘for’ (‘(’ Enumerators ‘)’ | ‘{’ Enumerators ‘}’) {nl} [‘yield’] Expr
                      |  ‘throw’ Expr
                      |  ‘return’ [Expr]
                      |  [SimpleExpr ‘.’] id ‘=’ Expr
                      |  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs ‘=’ Expr
                      |  PostfixExpr
                      |  PostfixExpr Ascription
                      |  PostfixExpr ‘match’ ‘{’ CaseClauses ‘}’
  PostfixExpr       ::=  InfixExpr [id [nl]]
  InfixExpr         ::=  PrefixExpr
                      |  InfixExpr id [nl] InfixExpr
  PrefixExpr        ::=  [‘-’ | ‘+’ | ‘~’ | ‘!’] SimpleExpr
  SimpleExpr        ::=  ‘new’ (ClassTemplate | TemplateBody)
                      |  BlockExpr
                      |  SimpleExpr1 [‘_’]
  SimpleExpr1       ::=  Literal
                      |  Path
                      |  ‘_’
                      |  ‘(’ [Exprs] ‘)’
                      |  SimpleExpr ‘.’ id
                      |  SimpleExpr TypeArgs
                      |  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs
                      |  XmlExpr
  Exprs             ::=  Expr {‘,’ Expr}
  BlockExpr         ::=  ‘{’ CaseClauses ‘}’
                      |  ‘{’ Block ‘}’
  Block             ::=  BlockStat {semi BlockStat} [ResultExpr]
  BlockStat         ::=  Import
                      |  {Annotation} [‘implicit’] [‘lazy’] Def
                      |  {Annotation} {LocalModifier} TmplDef
                      |  Expr1
                      |
```

In Imperative language, statments are something like `for`, `if`, `while`, `expression ;`, which has no return value. But here we can see they're all `Expr1`.

In Rust grammar, for example:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html

```
BlockExpression :
   {
      InnerAttribute*
      Statements?
   }

Statements :
      Statement+
   | Statement+ ExpressionWithoutBlock
   | ExpressionWithoutBlock

Expression :
      ExpressionWithoutBlock
   | ExpressionWithBlock

ExpressionWithoutBlock :
   OuterAttribute*†
   (
         LiteralExpression
      | PathExpression
      | OperatorExpression
      | GroupedExpression
      | ArrayExpression
      | AwaitExpression
      | IndexExpression
      | TupleExpression
      | TupleIndexingExpression
      | StructExpression
      | EnumerationVariantExpression
      | CallExpression
      | MethodCallExpression
      | FieldExpression
      | ClosureExpression
      | ContinueExpression
      | BreakExpression
      | RangeExpression
      | ReturnExpression
      | MacroInvocation
   )

ExpressionWithBlock :
   OuterAttribute*†
   (
         BlockExpression
      | AsyncBlockExpression
      | UnsafeBlockExpression
      | LoopExpression
      | IfExpression
      | IfLetExpression
      | MatchExpression
   )

IfExpression :
   if Expressionexcept struct expression BlockExpression
   (else ( BlockExpression | IfExpression | IfLetExpression ) )?

LoopExpression :
   LoopLabel? (
         InfiniteLoopExpression
      | PredicateLoopExpression
      | PredicatePatternLoopExpression
      | IteratorLoopExpression
   )

IteratorLoopExpression :
   for Pattern in Expressionexcept struct expression BlockExpression
```

We can see that, statements in `{` `}` block are expressions as well.

I want to define a very simple toy language grammar like Scala/Rust, but statements are still seperated by `;` like C/C++.

I'm using yacc/bison to define this syntax, here's my example:

```
primary_expr: ID
            | TRUE
            | FALSE
            | INTEGER
            | FLOAT
            | '(' expr ')'
            ;

postfix_expr : primary_expr
             | call_expr
             ;

unary_expr : postfix_expr
           | '-' unary_expr
           | '~' unary_expr
           | '!' unary_expr
           ;

binary_expr : unary_expr
            | binary_expr '+' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '-' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '*' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '/' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '%' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '==' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '!=' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '>' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '>=' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '<' unary_expr
            | binary_expr '<=' unary_expr
            ;

conditional_expr : binary_expr
                 | binary_expr '?' expr ':' conditional_expr
                 ;

assignment_expr : conditional_expr
                | unary_expr '=' assignment_expr
                ;

expr : assignment_expr
     | expr1
     ;

stmt : expr ';'
     | def
     ;

def : ...
    ;

expr1 : 'if' '(' expr ')' expr
      | 'if' '(' expr ')' expr 'else' expr
      | 'while' '(' expr ')' expr
      | 'return' expr
      | '{' stmt_list '}'
      | 'break'
      | 'continue'
      ;

stmt_list : stmt
          | stmt stmt_list
          ;
```

But this grammar works not as my expectations:

```
{
  if (true)
    return 1
  else 
    return 0;

  while (true) {
    print(1);
  };
}
```

But I want it to be like:

```
{
  if (true)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;

  while (true) {
    print(1);
  }
}
```

How should I fix it ?

Comment: You say that you want statements to be separated by `;`, but in your "I want it to be like" snippet, you are showing *expressions* terminated by `;`. So, which of the two is it?

Comment: In C, statements are NOT separated by `;`. Rather, *some but not all* statements are terminated with a `;`. You may look at an (old) C grammar [here](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html).

Comment: In Scala you can use `;`... if you don't want to use a new line to indicate that you finished one expression and want to create another one. This makes coder's like easier but it makes things harder for parser designer as they have much more complicated grammar, where new line might be or might not behave like `;` depending on context.

Comment: Somehow I find it disturbing that you keep referring to "Rust/Scala" as though they are the same language. Come to think of it C & C++ are also distinct languages.

Comment: You can think of the Rust grammar as if there were no statements. Everything is an expression, and what you call "statements" are just expressions with the special type `()`. The semicolon can be modeled as if it were a postfix operator that transforms the preceding expression into `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing semicolons (or any other list separator) is completely independent of the semantics of the list.

In other words, your desire to allow certain semicolons to be omitted has absolutely nothing to do with the question of what kind of things are the things separated (or terminated) by the semicolons. Whether a statement is to be considered a kind of expression (with a possibly empty value) or a different kind of entity is a semantic question. The only involvement of the parser is dividing lists of statements (or expressions) into individual components.

That's not to say that the semantic question is uninteresting. There's a lot to be said for (and against) the Rust semantics. But the question you seem to actually be asking is about syntax.

Whether or not statements are expressions, it is almost always the case the expressions are statements, or to put it more elegantly, that a list of statements -- for example, the body of an imperative function -- includes expressions, evaluated for their side effects (such as variable assignment, in languages where assignment is an expression, or calling a function which does something other than compute a return value, such as printing its argument.)

Commonly, the language will have at least one postfix operator, the function call operator. In the absence of expression delimiters, this necessarily produces an ambiguity, because an expression like

```
a ( b )
```

is not unambiguously a single expression. It could be the two expressions `a` and `( b )`. Similarly, if the language includes prefix and infix operator with the same spelling (`-` is the most common example, but there are many other possibilities), then an expression which uses the infix form could also be interpreted as two consecutive expressions, the second one using the prefix operator.

While it may be possible to resolve all these ambiguities through a variety of special-purpose rules, there are two common solutions: (When I say "statement" here, please read that as "syntactic entity in a list suitable for use as a block", or some such. As I said before, this has nothing to do with the thing being a statement or an expression; it's about how you write lists.)

1. Make all statements self-terminating. One example is the C language family, in which statements which are not otherwise self-terminating include a semicolon in their grammar. An example of a statement which *is* self-terminating is a block, which must start with a block open (`{`) and end with the matching block close (`}`). An example of a statement which is not self-terminating is a simple assignment statement.

   Since the `;` is a syntactic part of the assignment statement, it cannot be omitted even at the end of a block. Despite the fact that the `}` unambiguously signals the end of the enclosing block, the semicolon must still be present. (Beginners often stumble against the need to use a semicolon before an `else` token, which responds to the same logic.)

   A less rigid grammar could be used, in which semicolons become optional in contexts where the semicolon is not needed to separate list elements. Often, this flexibility is only accorded when the source code includes a newline, or in a few other very specific contexts. But this flexibility comes at a large cost for the compiler writer (and consequently for anyone else writing tools for the language), since it can considerable complicate both parsing and lexical analysis.
2. The list puts a separator between consecutive elements. This is common when the list is some kind of aggregate literal, but there are languages -- like Rust -- which use this style for blocks as well. In this style, the separator is part of the list syntax, rather than being part of the syntax for (certain) list elements. As a result, the separator is required even in contexts in which the preceding list element was unambiguously terminated. This leads to annoyances like

   ```
    {
        { ...
        };   /* Semicolon redundantly separates two list elements */
        { ...
        }    /* Here there is no semicolon because there is no following element. */
    }
   ```

   Again, a flexible grammar could be written, in which some of the redundant semicolons become optional. And again, this flexibility comes at a certain cost in implementation complexity.

   In many languages which use list separators, the list separator can be optionally appended to the end of a list (or certain lists). For example, in C the list of values used to initialize an array (which uses `,` as a separator) can contain an extra comma at the end, which is ignored. (This is particularly convenient for automatic generation of lists.) This is not the same as Rust, in which a block of statement (expressions) can end with an empty expression: `...; }`. This semicolon is not ignored; rather, it serves to change the value type of the block from the type of the last expression to the type of the empty expression. (Not all languages allow empty statements. For example, neither Python nor Posix shell allow two consecutive `;`.)

The above was written from the perspective of languages in which whitespace (including newlines) is basically ignored and semicolons are used as the terminator/separator. But there is another, very similar approach, in which *newlines* are the terminator/separator (and possibly semicolons are an alternative), but there are contexts in which newlines lose their syntactic significance. That's the case with Scala, for example. The difference between contextual semicolon insertion (as in ECMAScript) and newline deletion (as in Scala) is subtle, perhaps to the point of invisibility. (That is, it may be that the two conventions are simply two different ways of producing the same outcome.)

Now, how to implement these various syntaxes?

I'm not going to go into semicolon insertion/newline deletion here, although it is an interesting question. A variety of different mechanisms exist, some of which end up with surprising corner cases; the implementation details are language-specific and generally hand-written rather than generated automatically from the grammar. There are some answers on SO which discuss implementation in specific languages. (But there is one simple possibility below.)

#### 1. Semicolon as terminator

```
list : %empty
     | list expression
expression
     : simple_expression ';'
     | ';'
     | block
     | 'while' simple_expression 'do' expression
     | 'if' simple_expression 'then' expression 
     | 'if' simple_expression 'then' expression 'else' expression
     | ...
block: '{' list '}'
```

#### 2. Semicolon as separator

```
list : expression
     | list ';' expression
expression
     : simple_expression
     | block 
     | 'while' expression 'do' expression
     | 'if' expression 'then' expression
     | 'if' expression 'then' expression 'else' expression
block: '{' '}'
     | '{' list '}'
     | '{' list ';' '}'    // If you want optional trailing delimiter
```

There are some subtle differences between the two examples above, although they are not crucial to the respective models. They are just consequences of the way I happened to write the grammars, although I was mostly aiming for the simplest grammar.

First, although they both respond to the idea that "everything is an expression", the "semicolon as terminator" does not allow arbitrary expressions as the controlling expression of `while` and `if` statements in order to avoid requiring a semicolon before the following keyword [Note 1]. Second, they differ in the use of `;` before an `else`:

```
if x < y then min = x; else min = y; /* Grammar 1 */
if x < y then min = x else min = y;  /* Grammar 2 */
```

#### 2a. Variant: Semicolon as separator but optional after certain elements

The intent here is to remove (some) semicolons which are particularly annoying without making the grammar (much) more complicated. The semicolons which are optional are exactly and only those which follow the closing `}` in a `block`, so the logic does not take into account the following token at all. This more or less removes the need for those semicolons which would not have been required in Grammar 1, so it's perhaps closer to what you're looking for.

In order to implement that, we need to distinguish between expressions which end with a `block` and those which don't, which would be a bit awkward in the case of conditional and loop statements. Because my intent here is to avoid complexity, I simplified that issue by restricting compound statements to `block`s rather than allowing simple expressions. That restriction makes it possible to do away with the `then` and `do` tokens which separate the guard expression from the guarded block in the compound statements, which was necessary because we cannot have two consecutive `expression`s without creating ambiguity:

```
list : unterminated_list
     | terminated_list
unterminated_list
     : unterminated_expression
     | terminated_list unterminated_expression
terminated_list
     : terminated_expression
     | list ';'
     | terminated_list terminated_expression
expression
     : unterminated_expression
     | terminated_expression
unterminated_expression
     : simple_expression
/*   | ... /* Perhaps assignment */
terminated_expression
     : block 
     | "while" expression block
     | "if" expression block
     | "if" expression block "else" block
block: '{' '}'
     | '{' list '}'
simple_expression
     : term
     | simple_expression '+' term
term : IDENTIFIER
     | LITERAL
     | '(' expression ')'
     | term '(' ')'
     | term '(' arglist ')'
arglist
     : expression
     | arglist ',' expression
```

#### Notes

1. One language which does require a terminator in that position is Posix shell, in which you need to write, for example,

   ```
    if (( count == 3 )); then break
   ```

   But in most languages that semicolon would feel intrusive.)

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the 2a grammar. For example it will reject `{}{}`, requiring a semicolon between the two blocks. [Here](https://paste.chapril.org/?225533c128968a63#Ezcc6egy3yhBKExRJb2rJgTAB7wJgver5tz7W65QAQs2)'s a possible fix to make the semicolon optional.